# net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED as a result of trying to consume web api from HTML5 client

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Using the UpdateController.js file below:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module("app", []).controller ('UpdateController', function($scope, $http) {
    var onUpdatesComplete = function (response) {
        $scope.updates = response.data;
    };

    $http.get("//*******/api/Update/GetUpdates")
        .then(onUpdatesComplete);
});
}());
```

I want to populate the below div with a list of updates coming from a database:

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 updates">
                    <span style="font-size: 24px;">Latest Updates</span>
                    <hr style="margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;"/>
                    <div id="updateContainer">
                        <div class='media' ng-repeat="u in updates">
                            <a class='pull-left' href='#'>
                                <img class='media-object' src='images/updates/logo48.png' alt='logo'/>
                            </a>
                            <div class='media-body'>
                                <h5 class='media-heading'>
                                    <a href='#'>" + {{u.Title}} + "</a>
                                    <br/>
                                    <small>" + {{u.Subtitle}} + " " + {{u.PostingDate}} + "</small>
                                </h5>" + {{u.PostingText}} + "
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that when I load the page and console debug with Chrome, I get the following error:

```
GET http://*********/api/Update/GetUpdates net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Doing a cursory search over the issue doesn't yield much information. If anyone can shed some light on the issue, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I know how that souns but...are you sure the endpoint is there? Is the server up? Net errors usually happen when host is unavailable

Comment: I hit the api with Fiddler and got back the JSON I was looking for, but with the client app, I get the above result.

Comment: Can you try with any other client? Postman for example (it's chromes ext)

Comment: The api is our production api, its getting consumed by our current client site.

Comment: Yeah, but Postman is still a js client. If it doesn't work then I'm quite sure that it is your office's network configuration issue. Maybe there's some proxy server with custom DNS, which returns multiple IPs for your production API and browser can't handle the fail over? blind shot...

Answer (score 0):

For api query use $http.jsonp(url)